# Mono: Dispatcher.Invoke not implemented - Looking for workaround

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono

I would like to use the method `Dispatcher.Invoke` in mono. Unfortunately it throws a System.NotImplementedException.

**Question:**

What would be a workaround?

Note: I am using Mono 4.0.1 with Xamarin Studio 5.9.3 on OS X version 10.10.3.

**Update:**

As probably no general workaround exists here an example of the code I work with.

The call I have in my case is:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    execute(parameters);
}));
```

with execute just being a member variable of type Action

```
readonly Action<T> execute;
```

So I am interested to execute lambda statements on another thread.

Comment: Well, BeginInvoke() then.  Use a variable to store the result, an AutoResetEvent to block the thread.

Comment: I also get a NotImplementedException for BeginInvoke(). Maybe just the overload I am using is not implemented. I want to pass an Action.

Comment: I see lots of NotImplementedException throws in the Mono source code, this is unfinished code.  The one they did implement however is the one that takes a delegate.  Just don't make us guess at this when you just as easily can show your code.

Comment: This seems to be more a Xamarin question than a Mono question. As near as I can tell, they implemented different mechanisms for cross-thread dispatch depending on the platform. iOS: [InvokeOnMainThread()](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/), Android: [RunOnUIThread()](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/writing_responsive_applications/).

Comment: I am not looking for specific mechanisms on iOS or Android but for a general workaround ideally supported on all platforms running mono.

Comment: Looks like you have to write it by yourself :)

Comment: This basically means there exists no workaround to Dispatcher.Invoke() taking an Action I could use on Windows, Linux and OS X (in first approach I don't care about iOS and Android) to execute stuff on another threads. I will try to use the Delegate implementation of BeginInvoke.

Comment: As far as I see nothing in the Dispatcher works. Is there anything else that could be used?